# How to load different javascript libraries depending on browser?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a library that does not work in IE unfortunately, because IE does not support promises and other html5 features. I want to keep that library for Chrome & Firefox, but use a different one for IE. How can I separate the two like following:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myielib.min.js"></script>
<![else]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mychromelib.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Obviously, conditionally formatting only works on >IE9 browsers, but I wanted something similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can dynamic create script
like:

```
<script>
  var element=document.createElement('script');


  if(ie){
     element.setAttribute('src', 'ieSrc');
   }else{
     element.setAttribute('src', 'otherSrc');
   }
   document.getElementById("...").appendChild(element);
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used something like in the end. Found another solution using jQuery's $.getScript but it seemed to load slower than simply creating script elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can use browser detection functions on your page load event:

```
function BrowserDetection() {
    //Check if browser is IE
    if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") & gt; = 0) {
        // insert conditional IE code here
    }
    //Check if browser is Chrome
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") & gt; = 0) {
        // insert conditional Chrome code here
    }
    //Check if browser is Firefox 
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") & gt; = 0) {
        // insert conditional Firefox Code here
    }
    //Check if browser is Safari
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") & gt; = 0 & amp; & amp; navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") & lt; 0) {
        // insert conditional Safari code here
    }
    //Check if browser is Opera
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") & gt; = 0) {
        // insert conditional Opera code here
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.learningjquery.com/2017/05/how-to-use-javascript-to-detect-browser